# Is this suspicious? Two new users responding to an older question about an employer with praise of that employer

Tags: discussion, new-users

I'm starting to wonder - I've just seen the second response from a new user within 24 hours claiming the employer in https://sqa.stackexchange.com/questions/5867/applied-and-got-interview-within-hours-im-wondering-if-this-sqa-company-is-a-s is a good company and not at all a scam. Neither new user has added more than the bare minimum needed to create a profile.

Comment: That's what I initially thought until I saw a response from a guy I have worked with before and have great respect for.  I'm actually trying to get in touch with him, so will know how authentic or suspicious this place is, and satisfy my curiosity!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Is it suspicious? Yes. But there doesn't appear to be anything against our policy. All the information available indicates they're as distinct as two accounts might be expected to be. They all appear to be from Southern California, which makes sense as the company in question publicly states on their website that they are as well.

So it is possible that someone at the company went "Hey, we got some people saying we're shady. Are a couple guys willing to go share their experience with us?" In fact, I'd say it's likely! But that begs the question of whether or not that's a bad thing. If they work there, I'd say they most certainly have the information the OP is looking for. If they're omitting or providing misleading or inaccurate information, it's difficult to tell, and impossible to prove.

Comment: Fair enough. This isn't the kind of thing that's easy to deal with at the best of times.

Comment: With a little luck, being that they are SQA professionals, maybe they'll stick around and ask/answer a few questions.